# Why having assert before main() causing syntax error "error: expected ')' before numeric constant"?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, assert

Why assert is causing compilation error if I use it before main() call? It causes compilation error (Syntax error):

> test.cpp:4:8: error: expected ')' before numeric constant

Note: I'm trying to understand why I'm a getting a syntax error for calling it outside main. **That too related to something like "numeric constant", but not like function / macro called out side main function.** If the error was simpler like function / macro called out side main, then my question wouldn't have made any sense.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

assert(0); //If I comment assert from here, then it compiles fine.

int main()
{
  assert(0);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because you can't call `assert` from outside of `main` / a function.

Comment: Or more accuratelly, you can't call anything when not in function.

Comment: Because `assert` is actually code (or nothing).

Comment: You can do a `static_assert` on a static expression, e.g. `static_assert(sizeof(float)==4);`

Comment: Outside a function you can only have definitions and declarations, not general statements. Any book or tutorial or class (even bad ones) should have told you that. There are a few other exceptions to that rule, but they are very language-specific.

Comment: Choose one language C or C++

Comment: Currently this is unclear since the rules for C and C++ differ in this respect. Please remove one of the tags.

Comment: I have tried compiling the same code in 'c' and 'c++' compiler and got the same error. Hence, the C, C++, assert, debug tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all the other answers are "it didn't work because you can't do that", here's one that dives in to why the error message looks the way it does.

The short reason is compilers aren't smart, and they don't make good teachers.

When we, the experienced human programmers, look at this code

```
assert(0);
int main(void){}
```

we recognize the first line as an attempt to call a function, and use that as the starting point of an explanation about why it's invalid and what you should have written instead. There's a bit of mind-reading involved in the recognition of your intent, because you expressed that intent with incorrect code.

The compiler can't read your mind, and by definition the only way it can recognize your intent is if your code is valid. Since it doesn't understand what you're trying to do, it can't give helpful advice.

What the compiler is actually doing is just taking in your code, one token at a time, and parsing it according to a grammar. If the code is ungrammatical, there will be a point at which the next token doesn't match any grammar rules. The compiler then tells you what the offending token was. In this case the offending token was the numeric constant `0`.

The tokens preceding the `0` were parsed without complaint, but that doesn't mean they were interpreted the way you intended them.

It's hard to completely analyze this specific case because `<assert.h>` declares `assert` as a macro, and I don't know what it expands to on your system. To make the explanation a little easier, let's use a normal function:

```
/* sample program 1 */
foo(0);
int main(void){}
```

The above code fails to compile. My compiler says

```
error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before numeric constant
```

But this slightly altered version:

```
/* sample program 2 */
foo();
int main(void){}
```

compiles with only some warnings, because in old-style C, the first line is a valid declaration of a function `foo`, using the implicit `int` return type! If my intent was to somehow "call `foo` before main" then it's a total failure. If my intent was to only declare `foo` then I'm only guilty of using an obsolete language feature.

Now, knowing about the second sample, look back at the first sample. When the compiler reads the first 2 tokens, `foo` and `(`, everything is fine. The program still fits the grammar of (old-fashioned) C. Then it gets to the `0` and there's no way to proceed. So it tells me that the numeric constant is the problem.

Now what about those things it says it was "expecting"? Those are the tokens that can come next in a valid program. It suggests a declaration specifier list rather than an immediate `)`, because this is valid too:

```
foo(int);
int main(){}
```

Even this, using an old-style function definition, would be a possible continuation:

```
foo(i)
  int i;
{
}
int main(){}
```

Bottom line: whenever there's a parse error, the compiler reports the point where your program diverged **grammatically** from the set of all possible valid programs. The point where the parse diverged **semantically** from your intent is sometimes earlier. Sometimes a lot earlier. In that case, the compiler's "expected" tokens can be quite irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call free functions (be it `assert` (which is usually a macro, but still ends up being code that is run in global scope *like* a function) or any other function) from the global scope (you *can* however call functions as part of initializing a global variable (in C++)). That's why.

Move the `assert` into `main` or some other function.

Comment: Anonymous downvoter: care to explain why you believe this doesn't answer the question?

Comment: A couple of possibilities: `assert` is a macro, and you *can* call functions from the global scope (for example `const static int = do_something();`

Comment: You can have `static_assert(...)` outside a function though!

Comment: @Anthony Sottile - `static_assert` is a *declaration* though, *not* a function.

Comment: `you can however call functions as part of initializing a global variable` it is C++ only. In C you cant.

Comment: @P__J__ The question *is* tagged C++ (and C++11 as well).

Comment: is tagged C/C++

Comment: @P__J__ there's no such language, but sure, I'll mention it's C++ only for that bit.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I will explain if it was to complex. It means : "he used both tags in the question"

Comment: @P__J__ I *know* that. My *point* was that that is silly since the two languages have diverged enough at this point that the common subset is largely irrelevant and one should ask only about C *or* C++. Asking about both rarely makes sense.

Comment: I have tried compiling the same code in 'c' and 'c++' compiler and got the same error. Hence, the C, C++, assert, debug tags

Answer (score 0):

In the C language the code can be executed only inside the functions. So if you place any code outside the functions you will get the compile errors.

C++ allows global variables to be initialized by non constants as the constructors are called during the object creation.

Answer (score 0):

`main` is the entry point of your program.  The only code run before `main` is initialization code.  If you want to have assert run before `main`, you can have a global class with assert in its constructor, like:

```
class assert_class {
  assert_class() { assert(0); }
};
assert_class assert_here;

int main()
```

Comment: Your answer, Answers the question "How to call assert() before main? " but it doesn't explains any thing about the `syntax error: error: expected ')' before numeric constant`, which compiler is giving me. I tried running the code in different compiler but the same error. This gives me a feeling that there might be some specific reason behind such a weird syntax. Rather being simple error "function called out of main"

Comment: You can't have assert by itself because there is no way to get to the code.  The only code executed in your program is either init code (as I showed) or is called by main.  The assert code may as well be in a different file on a disk in a different room, since there is no path to get to the code.  The error is just saying that the parser expected `assert(` to be followed by `)`, not `0)`